# Blazor wasm not serving static files from wwwroot after deploying to IIS

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly, asp.net5

I'm developing a `.net 5.0 blazor wasm` application. When I run the app form visual studio using `IIS Express` and navigate to `https://localhost:5001/docs/simple.pdf`, the file is served in browser.

However the same does not work after deploying the blazor wasm app to `IIS`. I'm not getting any error instead my `Not Found` Route template screen gets loaded.

**Here is the screen prints:**

**`wwwroot` of blazor wasm app:**

[image]

**`IISExpress` loading the document:**

[image]

**`IIS virtual directory` path:**

[image]

**`IIS` not loading the document and display `NotFound` Route template:**

[image]

I also noticed none of the files in `wwwroot` is not directly accessible in browser in `IIS`. Please assist on what I'm missing.

Comment: When you configured IIS, did you actually pick port 44353?  Check the port in your IIS configuration to be sure.  If you didn't explicitly set, the default is port 80

Comment: I explicitly chose port 44353. https version will run on default port 80?

Comment: OK, I also tried 44353 and it works fine.  Another thing to check: make sure you have app.UseStaticFiles() in the Configure() method of Startup.cs in your server project.

Comment: this is a blazor wasm standalone deployment to IIS. `app.UseStaticFiles()` is not available here

Comment: Have you checked whether there are related error messages in the console? I did not find the NotFound error message in the image you posted. Or you can try to use failed request tracking to get detailed error messages.

Comment: I notice a weird thing now. first time when I request I get not found error as shown in screenshots. now if I press `ctrl+F5` its serving the document. Any idea on what needs to be done?

Comment: Seems it was a caching issue then.  However, I just posted a solution for others in the future.  For ASP.NET hosted app, the code I suggested is required.

Comment: but this happens every time for same request. every time i need to press `ctrl+F5` for document to be served.

Comment: Have you tried other browsers? Is it the same problem?

Comment: yeah I noticed the same behavior in all browsers. I suspect something else to be cause. I'm comparing my blazor wasm project with new scratch blazor wasm project to find the difference.

Comment: I'm close to finding the issue. When we use `<CascadingAuthenticationState>` and have a `app` element mapped to `body` element like `builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("body");` in `Program.cs`

Comment: Has your problem been solved?

Comment: nope. as of now I did another implementation as work around. But this is something I need to analyze further.

Comment: Are there any related error messages in the failed request tracking?

Comment: Does anyone have any update on this issue? I am having the exact same problem -- static file not found but ctrl + F5 would work. Also if I use a different browser which has never accessed the site before, the static file would work just fine. So it's basically after the Blazor WASM was downloaded it would not server the asp.net hosted static files initially, but a refresh would make it work.

Comment: @Franky I have kept this on hold and yet to analyze this. However in my initial analysis I have noticed that this happens when we have authentication configured for blazor wasm. (i.e.) if you have `AuthorizeRouteView` in `App.razor` this issue happens. Hope this helps you.

Comment: @fingers10 interesting ... I do have AuthorizeRouteView in my app because the entire app is under authentication. Can't do anything about that tho, must have authentication. But please keep me updated if you have a solution. Thanks!

Comment: @Franky sure. Please upvote my previous comment and question if you find it useful. This might bring others attention and we might get an early response from others.

Comment: I had this working, played about with the dependency injection and now, I'm in the same boat. I'm just leaving a comment so I can find this and write an answer when I fix it. Or to see when someone else fixes it.

Comment: @sanepete Please post an resolution once you find it. I'm also keeping an eye on this for a solution. I'll post if I find one.

Comment: Sorry, Fingers.
My problem was the CSS and images not found in IIS express under VS when running in debug.
I had the css and image folders in entirely the wrong project.
After I publish the project, I still have to manually copy these folders to the server.
My only other thought is: Is the pdf MIME type registered on IIS?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IIS. The issue is because of the `service-worker.published.js`. This is tracked in the following [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39592)

Answer (score 1):

Blazor WebAssembly is not involved in serving your files.

This is something to configure in IIS.

Comment: So how do you configure the IIS ?

Comment: Please can you assist on what configuration needs to be done in IIS?

Comment: Where are you running the Blazor WASM SPA from - how are you running localhost:44353?

Comment: I published my blazor wasm to IIS virtual directory that maps to localhost:44353 and accessing that from browser

Comment: I tend to agree with this answer.  I just posted a small Blazor WASM on my IIS and I could easily navigate to resources inside the wwwroot.  So I think the OP issue is not Blazor related.

Comment: @Jason D did you run the app on default 443 https port? Or any specific configuration needs to be done in IIS?

Comment: This has nothing to do with IIS. The issue is because of the `service-worker.published.js`. This is tracked in the following [github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39592)

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with `service-worker.published.js` file coming with `blazor wasm pwa` template. This has been reported in `dotnet/aspnetcore` repo.

Please follow the [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/39592) in github for more updates.